# bash homedir/multiple replacements?

Tags: bash, csv, glob

I am converting some xls files to CSV and need to extract a few things out of the filename, which looks like `~/foo2008-2012tmpl.xls`. I need `2008` and `foo2008-2012tmpl.csv` from the script when called with `foo`. My current version is:

```
file=(~/$1*tmpl*xls)
year=${file/*$1/}
year=${year/-20??tmpl.xls/}
loffice  "-env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/LibO_Conversion" --headless --convert-to csv $file --outdir .
localfile=$(basename $file)
csvfile=${localfile/xls/csv}
```

which works but it's not too pretty. Is it possible to do multiple string replacements with bash in one go or another way to get the `year` out of the filename? I tried extglob but the moment I added a `|` it never matched :/

Similarly, any way to remove the `/home/chx/...xls` part in one go from `$file`?

Comment: This is actually quite efficient.  You could do the same with `awk`, Perl, Python, or whatever, but that would involve running external programs.  It's fine as it is, if you ask me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Could be:

```
 year=$(expr "$file" : ".*$1\(....\)")
```